# How to scan one part of a file as a variable

Tags: c, file, variables

I'm a beginner and I have a code that requires me to scan the last number of a file into the variable a.

The file looks something like this:
car,4,50,800

If I want to scan the "800" into the variable a, how do I do that?

Answer (score -1):

In order to do it you have to read the data first and find the last occurance of the ',' char. Then you can get the data till let's say the end of file (EOF) or the new line char (\n). 8t all depends by the protocol you are using to store your data.